# merge duplicate file path in children - tree node

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am using the following json to build a tree structure.. if you notice, there are 2 children with identical file path borides and titanium, I need to merge them so that duplicate folders are not created. 
my output folder structure would be

```
SRD 13 
    - borides
        - titanium
            - srd13_B-102.json
            - srd13_B-103.json
```

with the following json, borides and titanium are getting repeated

Input json

```
parentObj = 

[{
"data": {
    "resTitle": "-JANAF Thermochemical Tables - SRD 13"
},
"children": [{
    "data": {
        "filePath": "borides"
    },
    "children": [{
        "data": {
            "filePath": "titanium"
        },
        "children": [{
            "data": {
                "filePath": "srd13_B-102.json"
            },
            "children": []
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "data": {
        "filePath": "borides"
    },
    "children": [{
        "data": {
            "filePath": "titanium"
        },
        "children": [{
            "data": {
                "filePath": "srd13_B-103.json"
            },
            "children": []
        }]
    }]
}]
}]
```

Output json would be

```
[{
"data": {
    "resTitle": "-JANAF Thermochemical Tables - SRD 13"
},
"children": [{
    "data": {
        "filePath": "borides"
    },
    "children": [{
        "data": {
            "filePath": "titanium"
        },
        "children": [{
                "data": {
                    "filePath": "srd13_B-102.json"
                }
            },
            {
                "data": {
                    "filePath": "srd13_B-103.json"
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
}]
}]
```

I am using the following script to merge the nodes but it only looks for identical filepath in first level, but in this case there are identical file paths in second level too..

```
const tmp ={}
ParentObj.children.forEach((o) => {
    const path = o.data.filePath;
    if (tmp[path]) {
        tmp[path].children = tmp[path].children || [];
        tmp[path].children.push(...o.children)
    } else {
        tmp[path] = o;
    }
});
ParentObj.children = Object.values(tmp);
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need some recursion to achieve this. I used `Array.prototype.reduce()` and recursive function `merge` to merge duplicate children nodes:

```js
const merge = (data) => {
  return data.reduce((result, current) => {
      let dup = result.find(d => d.data.filePath === current.data.filePath);
      if (!dup) {
          result.push(current.children && current.children.length > 0 ? {
              data: current.data,
              children: merge(current.children)
          } : {data: current.data});
      } else if (current.children && current.children.length > 0) {
          dup.children = merge(dup.children.concat(current.children));
      }
      return result;
  }, []);
};


let parentObj = 
[
   {
      "data":{
         "resTitle":"-JANAF Thermochemical Tables - SRD 13"
      },
      "children":[
         {
            "data":{
               "filePath":"borides"
            },
            "children":[
               {
                  "data":{
                     "filePath":"titanium"
                  },
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "data":{
                           "filePath":"srd13_B-102.json"
                        },
                        "children":[

                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "data":{
               "filePath":"borides"
            },
            "children":[
               {
                  "data":{
                     "filePath":"titanium"
                  },
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "data":{
                           "filePath":"srd13_B-103.json"
                        },
                        "children":[

                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(merge(parentObj), null, '  '));
```